# Video play in slow motion while converting webm file to mp4 using ffmpeg

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, electron, webm

I am using [ffmpeg-static-electron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-static-electron) in electron app for converting webm file to mp4 and that file will be play in mobile app as android and ios.

Here I am using ffmpeg command for converting webm file to mp4.

```html
  await execa(ffmpegPath, [
      '-i',
      inputPath,
      '-f',
      'mp4',
      '-vcodec','libx264', // video codec
      '-acodec','aac', // audio codec
      '-b:v', '6400k',  // video bitrate
      '-b:a', '4800k',  // audio bitrate
      '-strict', 'experimental', // standard
      '-r',
      '30000/1001',
      '-crf',
      '26',
      '-g',
      '16',
      '-movflags',
      'faststart',
      '-preset',
      'veryfast',
      outputPath,
    ])
```

I used '-g' to 16 for solving a dragging progress issue in android player but it increasing the app size.
Here you can check it out this https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/21892/why-cant-my-video-play-from-where-i-drag-the-playback-bar

Some time It is working fine but some time sound coming through garbled and sounded like robot with slow-motion video
Here is log file for normal video :https://textuploader.com/1o1ml

I want a best conversion (WebM to Mp4) with lower file size.Anyone please help.

Comment: Show the full log from the ffmpeg command.

Comment: Try lower audio bitrate, 4800k for audio is too much. And there might be problem because of changing video rate, try less flags and maybe you'll figure out what causes a problem...

Comment: @llogan:I attached a log file of normal video. But some time I got the case of garbled sound.I removed these   '-b:v', '6400k', '-b:a', '4800k', '-strict', 'experimental' properties.

Comment: That's not the complete log, and a log from a garbled output would be better.

Comment: @llogan:How can I, Because it is occurred randomly not always.

Comment: @llogan:Just provide me best way to convert a file.

Comment: @HardikKothari any progress on this? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: @bflemi3 Not got the issue so that time I have changed the way to achieve it. used a AWS services.